# How can I write Test Unit for CRUD in MVC5 / Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and unit testing, I don't know how can I write a test method for these methods:

```
// GET: Worts/Details
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var wort = (from s in db.Worts
                where s.ID == id
                select s).FirstOrDefault();

    if (wort == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(wort);
}

// GET: Worts/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

// POST: Worts/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Title,CreateDate,ClickCount,DislikeCount,LikeCount, Creator_ID")] Wort wort)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        wort.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
        wort.ClickCount = 0;
        wort.DislikeCount = 0;
        wort.LikeCount = 0;

        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        wort.Creator = db.Users.Where(x => x.ID == userId).FirstOrDefault();

        db.Worts.Add(wort);
        db.SaveChanges();

        try
        {
            this.mailSender.SendEmail(wort);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return View(wort);
}

// GET: Worts/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Wort wort = db.Worts.Find(id);

    if (wort == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(wort);
}

// POST: Worts/Edit/5
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Title,CreateDate")] Wort wort)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(wort).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(wort);
}

// GET: Worts/Delete/5
public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Wort wort = db.Worts.Find(id);

    if (wort == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(wort);
}

// POST: Worts/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    Wort wort = db.Worts.Find(id);
    db.Worts.Remove(wort);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I have written this code for testing, but it is not enough.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Details()
{
        // Arrange
        WortsController controller = new WortsController();

        int id = 22;

        // Act
        ViewResult result = controller.Details(id) as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull("Details", result.ViewName);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Create()
{
        // Arrange
        WortsController controller = new WortsController();

        // Act
        ViewResult result = controller.Create(new LikeWort.Models.Wort()) as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Edit(int? id)
{
        // Arrange
        WortsController controller = new WortsController();

        // Act
        ViewResult result = controller.Edit(id) as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Delete(int? id)
{
        // Arrange
        WortsController controller = new WortsController();

        // Act
        ViewResult result = controller.Delete(id) as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

Can anyone help me to write correct and complete test units for these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first recommendation is to separate your business logic from your plumbing.

Consider this code:

```
// GET: Worts/Details
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var wort = (from s in db.Worts
                where s.ID == id
                select s).FirstOrDefault();

    if (wort == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(wort);
}
```

First of all, let's move the database call into its own library.

```
// GET: Worts/Details
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var wort = WortService.GetWort(id);

    if (wort == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(wort);
}
```

Since WortService doesn't have any ASP.NET MVC stuff, it will be much easier to test.

Now lets look at the boilerplate. An interesting thing about ASP.NET MVC is that you can use "exception filters". You'll need two.

1. Convert ArgumentException to HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
2. Convert MissingDataException to HttpStatusCode.NotFound

Your service layer will throw these two exceptions as appropriate.

Now your MVC layer is just:

```
// GET: Worts/Details
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    var wort = WortService.GetWort(id);
    return View(wort);
}
```

That is so simple that it doesn't need its own test. The bulk of your testing is against WortService, the rest is covered by any UI tests you perform.

---

```
public class WortService { 
    public LWContext dbLW = new LWContext(); 
    public Wort GetWort(int? id) 
    {
        if (id == null)
             throw new ArgumentNullException("id");

        var wort = (from s in dbLW.Worts where s.ID == id select s).FirstOrDefault(); 
        return wort; 
    } 
}


public class ArgumentExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is ArgumentException)
        {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion , I did that. I created a class like you said, but I cant put : HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) , in my new class ... How can I write testMethod for that ?

Comment: this is the new class :     public class WortService
    {
        public LWContext dbLW = new LWContext();
        public Wort GetWort(int? id)
        {
            var wort = (from s in dbLW.Worts
                        where s.ID == id
                        select s).FirstOrDefault();

            return wort;
        }
    }

Comment: GetWort throws an ArgumentException. Your exception filter turns that into an HTTP Status code. (see updated example)

Comment: thanks for your help , Do u think this Method ( // POST: Worts/Create) also dont need to be tested?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straight forward approach from Microsoft

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/mocking-entity-framework-when-unit-testing-aspnet-web-api-2

It has to do with WebApi, will the work the same way for MVC.  I'd also using a mocking framework like Moq or FakeItEasy instead of create a TestStoreAppContext class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to detach the local version first and then do the update process

```
        var localEntity = dbContext.Set<theModel>()
            .Local
            .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == theModel.Id);
        if (localEntity != null)
        {
            dbContext.Entry(localEntity).State = EntityState.Detached;
        }
        dbContext.Entry(appModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
```